# Select for JSON with LEFT JOIN returns single element array when no data in the right table

Tags: sql-server, json

I'm exporting some data from an MS SQL server database as JSON.

There are two tables with a foreign key from table A to table B. It is a 0-many relationship, ie. a record in table A may have some data in table B, but it doesn't have to. Table A contains people records, and table B is a list of their current and previous addresses.

I'm using this statement to get the JSON data:

```
SELECT
    A.Firstname,
    A.LastName,
    HistoricAddresses.AddressLine1
    HistoricAddresses.AddressLine2
FROM
    People A
LEFT JOIN
    HistoricAddresses ON HistoricAddresses.PeopleId = A.Id
FOR JSON AUTO
```

This results in a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Firstname": "xyz",
        "Lastname": "xyz",
        "HistoricAddresses": [
            {
                "AddressLine1": "abc",
                "AddressLine2": "abc"
            },
            // more historic address records follow
        ]
    },
    // more records follow
]
```

This is all good until one record in the A table does not have any records in the B table. In that case, the JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Firstname": "xyz",
        "Lastname": "xyz",
        "HistoricAddresses": [
            {}
        ]
    },
    // more records follow
]
```

The contents of HistoricAddresses property is an array with a single empty element. It should be just an empty array.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Can you provide schema and sample  data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this by not using a LEFT JOIN, but a subselect.

Instead of

```
SELECT
    A.Firstname,
    A.LastName,
    HistoricAddresses.AddressLine1
    HistoricAddresses.AddressLine2
FROM
    People A
LEFT JOIN
    HistoricAddresses ON HistoricAddresses.PeopleId = A.Id
FOR JSON AUTO
```

I'm now using

```
SELECT
    A.Firstname,
    A.LastName,
    (SELECT 
        HistoricAddress.AddressLine1,
        HistoricAddress.AddressLine2
     FROM
        HistoricAddress
     WHERE
        HistoricAddress.PeopleId = A.Id
     FOR JSON AUTO) AS HistoricAddresses
FROM
    People A
FOR JSON AUTO
```

This completely leaves out the HistoricAddresses JSON property if there aren't any. My parser can work with that.

I haven't benchmarked it yet, though, so other solutions are definitely welcome.

Comment: Did you find another solution? It seems a bit crude. I have the same issue and when I deserialise in my C# object I am getting arrays that appear to have a a row but all their values are null. It's really annoying.

Comment: No, sorry. I did not. I went with the above solution. It is very fast. My current use case is about 100.000 records in table A, and 5-6 times that in table B.
It takes longer to zip and write the resulting JSON to file than the query time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use replace method for that;

```
SELECT REPLACE((
SELECT
    A.Firstname,
    A.LastName,
    HistoricAddresses.AddressLine1
    HistoricAddresses.AddressLine2
FROM
    People A
LEFT JOIN
    HistoricAddresses ON HistoricAddresses.PeopleId = A.Id
FOR JSON AUTO),'{}','')
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: While a replace probably would do the trick, the json string could become quite large, and it would be more of a brute-force solution instead of getting the SQL statement right.